# Access Microsoft Onenote book/section/page with Matlab

Tags: matlab, onenote, onenote-api, undocumented-behavior

I would like to read-out my locally stored Onenote book/section/page with Matlab and automatically search for specified strings. How can this be achieved? Does the Onenote API have to be interfaced or is there any easier way?

Here is what I have so far (online resources are scarce):

```
app=actxserver('onenote.application');
app.get(); %... to run some functions of the Onenote API?
```

I'm new to this and more information may be also useful for others. Here's the two references [[1](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/147019-control-onenote-with-matlab),[2]](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15352-publish-to-onenote?focused=5090469&tab=function)  that I found.

Related: [accessing onenote in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567055/read-microsoft-works-and-or-one-note-files-from-java)

Comment: please specify why you downvote. The question is broad, but there is not a lot of information to go on as far as I find.

Comment: update: I got around to read the *.one file as text, scanning for regions of interest. This is very hacky and bruteforce, but I'll post the answer if nothing better comes up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can peform authentication in Matlab (or just paste in a token) and issue web requests, you can use the search API.

`https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/pages?$search=...`

Note that search only works with consumer accounts/notebooks that are synced to the cloud.

---

I am not sure how you could interface this with matlab, but if you are running on Windows you could use the interop API (this would be a local solution)

[How To Write To A OneNote 2013 Page Using C# and The OneNote Interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27294510/how-to-write-to-a-onenote-2013-page-using-c-sharp-and-the-onenote-interop)

Comment: There's no way around the API? In Onenote 2007 the direct Matlab interface seemed to have worked (ref 1)...

Comment: Added this as well

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit how to access using Interprop / C#? I'm unsure if Matlab supports it actually

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about matlab. Just know that in windows, interop is an option.